# Ubuntu Image for GCE

Tags: server, custom-distributions

Given that google compute engine has moved to providing just debian and CentOS images but does allow custom images has anyone documented how to create a Ubuntu image that will run on GCE?

Answer (score 3):

As per [this announcement](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/curated-ubuntu-images-now-available-on.html), Google Compute Engine now have Ubuntu images curated by Canonical available.

You can find more information on how to spin up instances using these image in [the GCE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems#ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does through Customer Kernels.

You can use the following instructions on [How to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Google Compute Engine](http://doit-intl.com/blog/2014/5/31/how-to-install-ubuntu-server-on-gce)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Although the link may help answer the question, you may want to expand and improve your answer.